# Do we get world grid with date and time of visit of Sentinel 1 and Sentinel 2?

Tags: tiles, landsat-8, sentinel-2, sentinel-1, calendar

I have an ROI and I am interested in knowing the below for it

1. Tile Number
2. Date and Time of revisit as calendar for whole year

This will enable me to specify the tile number(s) and fetch the data for those specific revisit dates. The reason for asking specific dates is , I could fill in the gaps with data from other satellite missions like landsat8 at different dates.

Comment: Are you interested in past or future acquisitions? Getting a list of past acquisitions is easy - getting a complete list of all future acquisitions is close to impossible to predict.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

About Tiles:

There is a kml file provided by ESA that shows the location of each Tile. Overlay it with your study area and you will see which is your target tile.

About acquisition:

Acquisiton plans are also published by ESA. They are published as KML files. You can download historical data but the complete plan for the next year is not pusblished. Although Sentinel-2 has an pre-defined acquisition plan, variations may happen due to several reasons.

Check out the links:

https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/missions/sentinel-2/acquisition-plans
https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/missions/sentinel-2/data-products

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that the plan for Landsat-8 is only for a period of 3 days at most while for Sentinel-2 is a bit better with 10-15 days, so it's difficult to make an accurate prediction beyond that.

A bit old question but if someone still interested in the acquisition plan for Sentinel-2 and Landsat-8 you can check planned acquisitions for an AOI through [spectator.earth](https://spectator.earth) which parses the plans and gives you the answer right away, so you don't have to download the KML if don't need to(disclaimer: I co-created it).